# Routing/Pointing subdaomin in Laravel/Apache

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have a subdomain directory `products` on the server, like this : `http://products.example.com`

The directory contains other directories where each directory contains different web product, and have their own laravel setup.

So for example, if I want to visit a particular product say `myExample`, then I have to visit `http://products.example.com/myExample/public`

But I don't want `public` in the URL when visiting the home page of that particular product, so the new URL should be like this : `http://products.example.com/myExample`

How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess file in the Laravel root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It works on local server but not on production server